# How To Model A Two-Way Class In OOP

Tags: java, python, c++, ruby, oop

Imagine you have a message class as part of your online messaging system. A message instance can be viewed, edited and deleted by the sender, or viewed and deleted by the receiver.

Notice that both the sender and receiver can interact with the instance, but that some of the same state can't be shared among the sender and the receiver. If the receiver deletes the message, the sender should still be able to access it. Both should be able to read the same message, though, rather than have their own copy. You'll also have things like read receipts, where the other party should see the other side's state.

Obviously you could have a sender and receiver version of everything, like `is_sender_deleted` and `is_receiver_deleted`. This feels quite hard to work with, so I wasn't sure it was the right approach.

My question is, how could you model this using object-orientated programming? I tried searching for a while, but couldn't come across any discussions on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a subclass MessageData with the attributes that each will need, then construct two instances in your class, one for the sender and one for the receiver. That said, I don't anything wrong with simply having attributes for each in your message class.